# Using a Telerik RadOrgChart in an ASP MVC razor application

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, telerik

My company is in the process of rebuilding one of its applications. The old application is build using classic ASP whereas the new application is ASP MVC in combination with Razor.

One of the problems we are facing is that we need an organisational chart that works exectly like the one that exists within the telerik component set: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/orgchart/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

That is the one that is implemented within the old application. We are willing to use another component however this one has some specifics that work quit well for us. Its allows for client side editting, grouping, drag/drop and a couple more.

The question is, can we implement the telerik control in our new ASP MVC Razor application? And if so, how?

Comment: By default MVC does not allow using legacy ASP .Net server side controls. The idea is moving user interface logics to client side. I remember there was a workaround for ASP .Net controls to work with MVC but not sure if that works for Classic ASP controls as well.

Comment: Im not sure if it is really classic asp, telerik calls it ASP.NET Ajax. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, classic controls are reusable ASP and VBScript code that you can integrate into your application, whereas Asp.net controls are DLLs using Microsoft framework. First thing I'd consider it's contacting Telerik and ask them for a solution to migrate the control into new platform. As it is their control, it might be that this is not the first time such issue comes up.